# Erro ao buscar dados MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Não consigo buscar informação à base de dados usando php. Veja o código que implementei para buscar essa informação:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$sql = "SELECT pergunta, resA, resB,resC,resD,resE,acertaram,falharam,dificuldade,resposta,imgSrc FROM perguntas Where ID = 1";  //This is where I specify what data to query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){

    echo $result;

} else echo '<h1 style=" font-size: 30px; font-color: red ">ERRO AO PESQUISAR<h1><br /> <p>Ocorreu um erro enquanto se processava a querry.</p>';
```

O resultado é sempre o último `echo` e não consigo perceber porque. Quando corro essa querry no phpmyadmin ele retorna uma coluna por isso ele deveria entrar no `if`, mas não entra. Alguém me sabe apontar onde errei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É `$result` no lugar de `$sql`.

Outra coisa é que sua função está `mysql_num_rows`. Deve ser `mysqli_num_rows`, com `i` no `mysqli`.

```
$sql = "SELECT
    pergunta,
    resA,
    resB,
    resC,
    resD,
    resE,
    acertaram,
    falharam,
    dificuldade,
    resposta,
    imgSrc
FROM
    perguntas
WHERE
    ID = 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

}
else{

}
```

Comment: Continua exatamente igual após a troca. Ele parece que não devolve nada aqui `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: sey SGBD? não sei o que é isso, mas como tinha dito no phpmyadmin ele retorna uma coluna

Comment: SGBD é um sistema ou software que você gerencia o banco de dados, tipo o PHPMyAdmin. Alterei minha resposta, dê uma lida.

Comment: não acredito que caí nessa. Assim já entra no `if` (mesmo sem a comparação), posso concluir que ele buscou a informação da coluna correspondente?

Comment: Pode sim. Não precisa da comparação. Se for maior que `0` automaticamente é TRUE, então ele entra no `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando o raw da query ao invés de passar o resource:

```
mysql_num_rows($sql)
```

Além disso, está sendo utilizado a função mysql_* e não mysqli_* como requirido.
O correto seria::

```
mysqli_num_rows($result)
```